# select single as well as multiple file from SD card in android

Tags: android, android-afilechooser

In my application I have a button clicking which will open up a file chooser and after choosing files, I am able to get the selected file's uri inside onActivityResult(). However, the issue what I am finding is I always have to select multiple files for getting the uri path. In case of single file selection, no uri data is returned in onActivityResult(). Below I am posting my code. Please have a look.

```
 Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());
            Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            chooseFile.setDataAndType(uri, "resource/folder");
            chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
            chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

            //chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);


            chooseFile.setType("*/*");
            chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
            startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

onActivityResult():

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch(requestCode){
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE:
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){

                if (data != null) {
                    ClipData clipData = data.getClipData();
                    if (clipData != null) {

                        Log.d("attachmentnumber",clipData.getItemCount()+alst_attachmentNames.size()+"");
                        if(clipData.getItemCount()>5 || (clipData.getItemCount()+alst_attachmentNames.size())>5  )
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(myContext,"attachment of 5 or less than 5 items are allowed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < clipData.getItemCount(); i++) {
                                ClipData.Item item = clipData.getItemAt(i);
                                Uri uri = item.getUri();

                                //In case you need image's absolute path
                                try {
                                    String path= getFilePath(getActivity(), uri);
                                    alst_attachmentPaths.add(path);
                                    alst_attachmentNames.add(path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/")+1));
                                    Log.d("pathValues", path);
                                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                            LinearLayoutManager layoutManager=
                                    new LinearLayoutManager(myContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                            RecyclerView.Adapter attachmentAdapter = new attachmentAdapter(myContext, alst_attachmentNames);
                            rvw_attachmentList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                            rvw_attachmentList.setAdapter(attachmentAdapter);

                        Log.d("arraylistValues", Arrays.toString(alst_attachmentNames.toArray())+"/n"+
                                Arrays.toString(alst_attachmentPaths.toArray()));
                    }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: where do you call `Intent#getData()`?

Comment: @pskink: inside onActivityResult(), through the data parameter

Comment: no, i dont see any `getData` calls inside `onActivityResult`

Comment: As I have to get all of the data ( that can besingle file or multiple files), instead of getData() , I am using getClipData()

Comment: `"In case of single file selection, no uri data is returned in onActivityResult()"` so what do you have in `data.getData()`?

Comment: Let me just have a look

Comment: @pskink: Thank you.. Issue resolved. Didn't added any getData() for single data previously.